# Favicon not implemented

Tags: html, css, favicon

Added favicon files to the github page

and pasted the following code below . It's not working though! I'm on chrome. What could be the problem?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en-us">
<head>
    <link href="fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900"; rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/apple-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-icon-180x180.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="/android-icon-192x192.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/favicon-96x96.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/ms-icon-144x144.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: are the images in the root-folder, since you reference them with a leading `/`? Maybe you need to adjust the path

Comment: I agree with @ThomasAltmann, it might just be wrong paths.

Comment: @ThomasAltmann Sorry not sure what a root-folder is...  This is what I did http://imgur.com/a/Jk5j6  What should I do? How do I adjust path..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reset cookies in your browser (in Chrome just `ctrl+shift+r`)

Check in developer console if there is no 404 errors and icons coming through.

Like all you need to have:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="apple-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="android-icon-192x192.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="apple-icon-96x96.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="apple-icon-16x16.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your paths in the `href` attribute are wrong. You are telling the browser they are in the root-directory of your project (which in this case, is the first thing that comes up when you open the page in github, [your screenshot as reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fhV2.jpg))

You have a folder named `Favicon.ico` (which I would change into something like `icons`, as `.ico` is usually associated with a file)

So, in your HTML you have to adjust the paths, so the browser knows in which directory these icons are, e.g.:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/Favicon.ico/favicon-32x32.png">
```